# SSL Configuration for Nginx and Apache

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, domain, nginx

I've server now running Nginx with SSL Wildcard installed but I need to add SSL to my new server running Apache, How to that?

Case:
The nginx server is still active with domain example.com
and add new SSL to domain lik new.example.com with web server Apache.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sudo a2enmod ssl

sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl

on new apache2 version, configuration files need to have .conf extension, so in this case the two previous commands are now :

sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf

sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf

sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf
and chnage :

SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Refrence :https://hallard.me/enable-ssl-for-apache-server-in-5-minutes/

Comment: There are 2 server, 1 server is with nginx and 1 is with webapache, it doesnt work

Comment: There are two ways this can be done. The first is sharing the private key to every server that is going to host the site, the second is to use an SSL proxy that holds the private key on the edge of a private network of servers running the site (or possibly using alternate encrypted communication). Both have their strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Can you show some link mohammad?

Comment: you can use SNI :  which sends a site visitor the certificate that matches the requested server name.   example using SNI :   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-ssl-certificates-on-one-ip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04